# In SSMS cannot set compatibility level to 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have SQL Server Management Studio v17.4 and I am trying to set the compatability level of a database to SQL Server 2016 (130).  In the database properties window It only lists 2008 (100), 2012 (110), and 2014 (120) levels.  If I try to use the command

```
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL= 130
```

I get the error

> Valid values of the database compatibility level are 100, 110, or 120.

This is a major problem because I am trying to run a local copy of my company's database, and more and more changes are getting checked into source control that use TSQL 2016 keywords like `AS TIMEZONE`.

How can I set this to 2016?

Comment: ... is the server 2016 or 2014? Right click on the server in SSMS and go to Properties. Update the post with the Version number. `SELECT @@VERSION` should also give you the answer (hint: it's probably 2014).

Comment: Check your server version you're working against: `SELECT @@VERSION` - what do you get??

Comment: It turns out I had 2017 and 2014 installed side by side. Thanks